# Read multi-record avro using spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, avro

I'm trying to read avro messages from Azure Iothub (eventhub/kafka) in Databricks using following code:

```
df = spark.read\
            .format("kafka")\
            .option("subscribe", "topic-name")\
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "my-iothub-workspace.servicebus.windows.net:9093") \
            .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")\
            .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")\
            .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", f'kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="{connection_string}";')\
            .load()

display(df.select(from_avro(df.value, jsonAvroSchema, options={"mode":"PERMISSIVE", "compression": "deflate"}).alias("data")).select("data.*"))
```

The schema is the following:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Avro_SchemaAll",
  "namespace" : "ApacheAvro.Types",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "Timestamp",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "SensorId",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "SensorValue",
    "type" : [ "null", "float" ]
  }]
}
```

The point is that every kafka message contains an avro with multiple records inside of it. Therefore, if I download the kafka message and use avro-tools to read it I get something like:

```
{message_1}
{message_2}
...
{message_n}
```

where messsage_i has the previous schema. This messages are build with the following C# code:

```
using (var writer = AvroContainer.CreateGenericWriter(_avroSchema, buffer, Codec.Deflate))
  {                         
     using var streamWriter = new SequentialWriter<object>(writer, _readings.Count);
     for (var i = 0; i < _readings.Count; i++)
     {
          streamWriter.Write(_readings[i]);
     }
  }
```

How can I use spark to read multi-record avros from kafka/eventhub/iot-hub?

Comment: What do you mean each Kafka message has multiple avro records? Like an array?

Comment: yes, like an array but the schema is not an array. Could the schema be wrong even avro-tools opens the file correctly?

Comment: I don't fully understand what data you've produced into Kafka. Avro files can contain multiple records, yes, but Kafka should not be used for "whole file transfer". Each message should be an _individual record_ from that file. There's no such thing as a "multi record Avro" format that doesn't contain arrays or maps

Comment: @OneCricketeer probably I'm wrong sending the whole file but I can't change it. By multi-record avro I mean a file/a binary message with multiple records.

Comment: "Sending" how? Please share your producer code as a [mcve] as well. It's hard to tell you how to consume your data without seeing how it was sent/serialized.